# Getting linker error while trying to link class from another project

Tags: c++

in VS 2008,I got this linker error.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Classname::Classname(void)"
```

I could see `classname::classname()` constructor definition is already defined in my file but still I'm getting this linker error.

I'm trying to link this class from other project. I've already give all the input path in the properties. I can able to browse the file via GO to definition from VS tool.

Comment: Please show us some code, even if you think it's obviously OK.

Comment: Check the **case** of the class name, constructor, etc. What you posted as the error message and what you posted as your assurance it exists are *not* the same.

Comment: Check that the source file is actually being compiled (i.e it is included in your Visual Studio project).

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor is defined in `.cpp` file, make sure this `.cpp` file is added to your project.

Comment: Given the information available, this seems like the most likely cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, 1)Case is same, typo error 2) source file is also compiled along with this project. 3).cpp is also added to the project when I'm trying to create a object, i'm getting this linker error i.e classname obj; < linker error mentioned above > .